# how to configure AspectJ with JSR 286 Generic Portlet ??? any link

Tags: liferay, portlet, aspectj, jsr286

we are developing portal application using JSR-286 portlet inside liferay tomcat.We are creating our portlet extending Generic Portlet.Now I want to apply logs on doView() and doModify() methods using AspectJ. I tried with Spring AspectJ. But Spring AspectJ works only on spring managed beans.

any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved above problem.

here are some solution to get it done.

*Create an Aspect*

```
           @Aspect
     public class TestAspect {

 TestAspect (){

    System.out.println("TestAspect Initialized");
}
@Pointcut( "execution(public void doView*(javax.portlet.RenderRequest,javax.portlet.RenderResponse) throws java.io.IOException, javax.portlet.PortletException)" )

 private void testDoView() {
    }
       @Around("testDoView()")
      public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
      {

    System.out.println("AROUND ADVICE START");

try{
    joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
        }catch(PortletException portletException){
    System.out.println("[AROUND ADVICE] :"+portletExceptionio.getMessgae());

}catch(IOException ioException){
    System.out.println("[AROUND ADVICE] :"+ioException.getMessgae());
}
catch(Throwable throwable){
    System.out.println("[AROUND ADVICE] :"+throwable.getMessage();
}

System.out.println("AROUND ADVICE EXIT");

    }

      }
```

some *.jar files are AspectJ binaries:

aspectjrt.jar - necessary in runtime for correct aspects processing;

aspectjtools.jar - contains implementation of aspectj compiler;

aspectjweaver.jar - bridge between aspectj logic and java instrumentation;

1.*In command line enviroment* (with Ant-build.xml)

```
 **There are three ways to inject instructions implied by AspectJ aspects:**


<project name="aspectj-example" xmlns:aspectj="antlib:org.aspectj">

<property name="src.dir" value="src/main/java"/>
<property name="resource.dir" value="src/main/resources"/>
<property name="target.dir" value="target"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${target.dir}/classes"/>
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.aspectj"
        resource="org/aspectj/antlib.xml"
        classpath="${resource.dir}/aspectjtools.jar"/>
 <path id="aspectj.libs">
    <fileset dir="${resource.dir}"/>
</path>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${target.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${target.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
</target>

way 1: compile-time weaving

 <target name="compile-time" depends="clean">
    <aspectj:iajc source="1.5" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpathref="aspectj.libs" destDir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <java classname="com.aspectj.TestTarget" fork="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="aspectj.libs"/>
            <pathelement path="${classes.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

way 2: post-compile weaving

```
<target name="post-compile" depends="clean">

    <echo message="Compiling..."/>
    <javac debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpathref="aspectj.libs" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>

    <echo message="Weaving..."/>
    <aspectj:iajc classpathref="aspectj.libs" inpath="${classes.dir}" aspectpath="${src.dir}" outJar="${classes.dir}/test.jar"/>


</target>
```

way 3: load-time weaving

```
     <target name="load-time" depends="clean">

     <echo message="Compiling..."/>
     <javac debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" classpathref="aspectj.libs"               destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
     </target>
     </project>
```

2.In Ecilpse (IDE environment)

```
      select your project,than select configure->convert to AspectJ Project.
```